# ¿Cómo evitar que OpenFileDialog confunda .exe con .url?

Tags: windows-forms, .net

Tengo un problema peculiar, he creado un código para poder organizar y ejecutar accesos directos,pero mi problema está con la Clase OpenFileDialog.

Después de haberle puesto un filtro, para que solo tenga encuentra los .exe, resulta que es incapaz de diferenciar entre un .exe y un .url que imita a un .exe.

```
 OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
            file.Filter = "Executable (*.exe)|*.exe";
            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && file.CheckPathExists && file.CheckFileExists)
            {
                textResult.ReadOnly = false;
                textResult.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);
                textResult.ReadOnly = true;
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen puesto como a pesar del filtro .exe muestra tanto el acceso directo del .exe como el de una url y si seleccionas el de la url salta "Catastrophic failure".

¿Alguna idea?.

Comment: Que te interesa que no se muestre o que si lo seleccionan muestre un mensaje de que ese no es un acceso directo valido?

Comment: Prefiero que no se muestre, pero cambiar el mensaje tambien me vale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré una solución.

```
 OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
            file.Filter = @"Objects (*.exe;*.url)|*.exe;*.url";


            file.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
            {
                if(file.CheckPathExists && file.CheckFileExists) {
                    textResult.ReadOnly = false;

                    textResult.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);
                    textResult.ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }
```

El problema original era que cuando yo buscaba .exe me aparecian .url que eran accesos directos de por ejemplo juegos de steam.

La solución fue:

```
file.Filter = @"Objects (*.exe;*.url)|*.exe;*.url";
```

Añadir al filtro un filtro mixto entre .exe y .url.,de esa forma que cuando intentase ejecutar un acceso directo de ese tipo no daria error.